# How do I keep Glassfish from creating a new session for each request?

Tags: glassfish, ejb, java-ee-6, jax-rs, ejb-3.1

Glassfish 3.1.1
Jersey 1.8

I have the following stateless session bean exposed as a JAX-RS resource.  *VehicleResource* is contained in a WAR, with the other EJBs in an EJB-JAR.  The entire app is packaged and deployed as an EAR.

```
@Stateless
@Path("/")
@DeclareRoles({"production"})
public class VehicleResource {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(VehicleResource.class.getName());
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Context
private UriInfo uriInfo;

@EJB
private VehicleManagementLocal vehicles;

@EJB
private VehicleAliases aliases;
....
```

I have a Jersey Client making requests to the restful service.  A session is created for each request.  Is this normal/expected?  With many requests, the server quickly runs out of memory.  Why is this happening, and is there any configuration/code changes I can make to prevent a new session per request?

**Edit**
Actually, only one instance of the session bean is created.  I am simulating a load by repeatedly hitting a URI.  I have changed the session timeout to 5 minutes (from 30).  The sessions now expire and can be garbage collected fast enough to keep the server from running out of memory.  "Web Container: Session Statistics" in glassfish monitoring section shows I have ~50,000 active sessions.

Answer (score 2):

> A session is created for each request

Do you mean a new instance of the stateless session bean is created for each request? If so, and if you don't want this to happen, you can annotate your session bean with `@Singleton`.

Also if the exposed service is read only, you can annotate it with `@javax.ejb.Lock(READ)` to improve concurrency and performance.

Finally, if you don't want use singleton but want to limit the number of instances the container creates for you have a look at the pool size settings: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beahx.html

Comment: I almost typed the same answer but got to thinking about how restless by design is supposed to create a new thread. What happens when the pool is exhausted and the next request comes in? What does the client see?

Comment: When the pool is exhausted, the container waits for a bit longer, so that an unused instance is returned back to the pool that can be used to serve the request. However if the container can not find such an instance for say 30 seconds (this is configurable) it times out and the request won't be served.

Comment: See edits to original question.  Thanks for the tip on Lock(READ), I will check that out.  I might be totally off-base here, but I was thinking a Servlet could handle many connections without creating Sessions.  I imagine that if I were to use a servlet,  I would loose the EJB injection goodness.  I wonder if I could inject the web session in the VehicleResource EJB and invalidate it in each method?